# Set local computer name and static IP address on systems running on Windows 10

Tags: vbscript, windows-10

I am trying to rename computers and assign them a static IP by running a VBScript.
Name and IP will be read from a text file.

I have successfully used the scripts below on Windows 7 but it doesn't work on Windows 10

To rename Windows 7 computers:

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colComputers = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem")

Dim objComputer 'as Win32_ComputerSystem
For Each objComputer In colComputers
    err = objComputer.Rename("NewName")
Next
```

To set Windows 7 static IP:

```
Set colNetAdapters = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration where IPEnabled=TRUE")

strIPAddress = Array("192.168.1.xxx")
strSubnetMask = Array("255.255.255.x")
strGateway = Array("192.168.1.xxx")
strGatewayMetric = Array(1)
```

I can't find a version of that script that would works on Windows 10.

Comment: I believe you need to include a username and password for an administrative account, so this line: `err = objComputer.Rename(NewName)` should be something like `err = objComputer.Rename(NewName, Password, Username)`. Google the exact syntax.

Comment: This looks like a job for PowerShell.

Comment: Ashleedawg, I use both vbscript and vba for this project. I have tried the line you suggested and it still did not work.

Comment: Mathieu, I know it would probably be a shorter code with Powershell, but I wanted to complete the whole project in vb.

Comment: For `rename` method of the `Win32_ComputerSystem` class: use the _locator object connection_, which is [SWbemLocator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmisdk/swbemlocator-connectserver) for VBScript. Do not use the moniker connection.

Comment: i can't understand what you mean by "Name and IP will be read from a text file." while the script you write down have no mention to any text file read from. If you like to write all your configuration to file and you like script read from this just confirm that so ill edit my script to fulfill this task .thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change the Computer Name :

```
' run script as administrator

 If WScript.Arguments.Length=0 Then
  CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute "Wscript.exe",Chr(34)&WScript.ScriptFullName&Chr(34)&" RunAs",Null,"runas",1
  WScript.Quit
 End If 

' change Computer Name for registry
Dim newComputerName : newComputerName="android"
Dim sh : Set sh = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Dim strRegPath
strRegPath="HKLM\system\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\NV Hostname" 
sh.RegWrite strRegPath, newComputerName
WScript.Sleep 1000
strRegPath="HKLM\system\CurrentControlSet\control\ComputerName\ComputerName\ComputerName"
sh.RegWrite strRegPath,newComputerName
WScript.Sleep 1000
' restart the Computer
For Each Computer In GetObject("Winmgmts:{(Shutdown)}").InstancesOf("Win32_OperatingSystem")
Computer.Win32Shutdown(6) 
Next
'sh.Run "cmd.exe /c shutdown /r /f /t 00",0,False
```

After restart you can use this script to change the IP address and DNS

```
' run script as administrator
 If WScript.Arguments.Length=0 Then
  CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute "Wscript.exe",Chr(34)&WScript.ScriptFullName&Chr(34)&" RunAs",Null,"runas",1
  WScript.Quit
 End If 

' change Computer IP and DNS 
myInterfaceName="wi-fi"
myIP="192.168.1.7"
myMask="255.255.255.0"
myGateway="192.168.1.100" 
myPreferredDNS ="2.2.2.2"
myAlternatedDNS ="8.8.8.8"
Set sh=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
sh.Run "cmd.exe /c netsh interface ipv4 set address """&myInterfaceName&""" static "&myIP&" "&myMask&" "&myGateway &" 1",0,False
sh.Run "cmd.exe /c netsh interface ipv4 Set dnsservers """&myInterfaceName&""" static "&myPreferredDNS&" primary",0,False 
sh.Run "cmd.exe /c netsh interface ipv4 Add dnsservers """&myInterfaceName&""" "&myAlternatedDNS&" Index=2",0,False 
sh.Run "cmd.exe /k netsh interface ipv4 show config ",1,False
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take your Tcpip configuration (IP and DNS) and the computer new name from external Text File

first create your Text file in this way of Format remove what exist between quotation marks and add your configuration but don't change anything else Then save this file for example "IP.txt":

```
newComputerName="THE_MACHINE"
Name="wi-fi"
Address="192.168.1.7"
Mask="255.255.255.0"
Gateway="192.168.1.1" 
DNS1="2.2.2.2"
DNS2="8.8.8.8"
```

Then use this script to change the name of the computer

```
' run script as administrator
 If WScript.Arguments.Length=0 Then
  CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute "Wscript.exe",Chr(34)&WScript.ScriptFullName&Chr(34)&" HOLLOPOST",Null,"runas",1
  WScript.Quit
 End If 

' Get the new computer name from Text File
myTextFilePath="C:\USERS\ENG\DESKTOP\IP.TXT"                   'add here the full path of text fill
T = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(myTextFilePath).ReadAll
a=Split(T,vbcrlf)
For i=0 To UBound(a)
If InStr(1,a(i),"newComputerName",1)>0 Then
newComputerName=right(a(i),len(a(i))-16)
End If
Next 
' change Computer Name for registry
Dim sh : Set sh = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Dim strRegPath : strRegPath="HKLM\system\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\NV Hostname" 
sh.RegWrite strRegPath, newComputerName
WScript.Sleep 1000
strRegPath="HKLM\system\CurrentControlSet\control\ComputerName\ComputerName\ComputerName"
sh.RegWrite strRegPath,newComputerName
WScript.Sleep 1000
' restart the Computer
For Each ComputerObject In GetObject("Winmgmts:{(Shutdown)}").InstancesOf("Win32_OperatingSystem"): ComputerObject.Win32Shutdown(6) : Next
```

Then After Restart the Computer use the second script to change the IP configuration and DNS :

```
' run script as administrator
 If WScript.Arguments.Length=0 Then
  CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute "Wscript.exe",Chr(34)&WScript.ScriptFullName&Chr(34)&" HOLLOPOST",Null,"runas",1
  WScript.Quit
  End If

'Get Ip configuration from Text file
myTextFilePath="C:\USERS\ENG\DESKTOP\IP.TXT"
 T = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(myTextFilePath).ReadAll
a=Split(T,vbcrlf)
For i=0 To UBound(a)
 If  InStr(1,a(i),"Name",1)>0 Then
      myInterfaceName=a(i) 
  ElseIf  InStr(1,a(i),"Address",1)>0 Then
      myIP=a(i)
  ElseIf  InStr(1,a(i),"Mask",1)>0 Then
      myMask=a(i)  
  ElseIf  InStr(1,a(i),"Gateway",1)>0 Then
     myGateway=a(i)
   ElseIf  InStr(1,a(i),"DNS1",1)>0 Then
     myPreferredDNS=right(a(i),len(a(i))-5)
   ElseIf  InStr(1,a(i),"DNS2",1)>0 Then
     myAlternatedDNS=right(a(i),len(a(i))-5)  
 End If 
 Next 
' change Computer IP and DNS 
Set sh=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
sh.Run "cmd.exe /c netsh interface ipv4 set address """&myInterfaceName&""" static "&myIP&" "&myMask&" "&myGateway &" 1",0,False
sh.Run "cmd.exe /c netsh interface ipv4 Set dnsservers """&myInterfaceName&""" static "&myPreferredDNS&" primary",0,False 
sh.Run "cmd.exe /c netsh interface ipv4 Add dnsservers """&myInterfaceName&""" "&myAlternatedDNS&" Index=2",0,False 
sh.Run "cmd.exe  /k netsh interface ipv4 show config",1,False
```